# How to set a dimens for google pixel

Tags: android, android-layout, dimensions

In my app, there is a very special adaptive problem, I need set a dimens for those devices：

[image]

I look up here： https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources
so I set w411dp-h711dp-xxxhdpi.dimens， but not work in my app， it still get dimens from  xxxhdpi.dimens

Comment: why you want the dimentions to work only for Google Pixel? doesn't your app going to work on the other devices?

Comment: Hi buddy, not only for Google Pixel, but there is a place which I need to set a special dimens for google pixel or some else device which is 411 dp * 731 dp

Comment: I think that you are doing wrong trying to fit exact device in any case. It's bad idea in general. The reason for that is that there are hundreds of different aspect ration, device screens, densities, etc. So you can't fit all them. Just use relative values, not exact ones (weights, etc.)

Comment: Yes what you talk is all right, Buy in my very special case, I just need set a dimens.xml for w411dp * h711dp devices :))) ， just like set a dimens.xml for tablet